# How to put a pop up drawing pad dialog in an e-book and editable using a PDF reader?

Tags: applications, pdf, ebook-reader, ebooks

Many e-book readers I've tried to download have a feature i.e. taking notes in a pop-up dialog that you can fill out with text only and also edit the pdf so it can be drawable. I wonder if I could make a note, but not as a text, but as a draw and simply put it in a small icon that could pop up when it's tapped.

So, imagine I have a math E-book, and I want to do some exercises on my tablet using an e-book reader. Typing my answers is nearly impossible since math requires many forms of symbols and sort, so, it would be really cool if I could put a pop up icon, when it's tapped it would appear as a drawing pad to write all the answer using my stylus (pure handwriting).

This is the icon that I expect to put that tappable

[image: icon]

And this is what happens when I tap the icon

[image]

However the android app above i.e. Adobe Acrobat doesn't have such a feature for drawing pad in the icon. It's only able to put a text in it. I wonder if that's possible. Mayhap a 3rd party app? Do you have any idea what app I could do or what I should do? Thanks.